# Angular HTTP POST not firing

Tags: angular, http, post, asp.net-web-api

I'm having trouble while making a simple call from my NG app to my ASP.NET Core WebAPI. The code is the one following:

```
  this.http.post(actionUrl, credentialsDto)
  .map((data: Response) => {
    if (data !== null) {
      localStorage.setItem(this.tokenStorageKey, JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

I tried to log my "data" callback parameter, but adding a call to console.log() in my if statement results in nothing (means i have no console output at all). Meanwhile if i add a console.log() call before or after the call, but in the same function, they are perfectly executed.

Does anyone know what's happening here? I'm a JS novice, so don't blame me.
I'm using the HTTP client native in Angular 5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need also to subscribe to the `Observable`. `Observable` will not fire if you haven't subscribed to it.

```
this.http.post(actionUrl, credentialsDto)
         .map((data: Response) => {
               if (data !== null) {
                  localStorage.setItem(this.tokenStorageKey, JSON.stringify(data));
               }

               return response;
          }).subscribe(response => /* something here */).
```

Starting from *RxJS 5.5* you can't use `map` operator like you did. You need to use it inside `pipe` function.

### ***RxJS 5.5*** and higher approach

```
this.http.post(actionUrl, credentialsDto)
         .pipe(map((data: Response) => {
               if (data !== null) {
                  localStorage.setItem(this.tokenStorageKey, JSON.stringify(data));
               }

               return response;
          })).subscribe(response => /* something here */).
```

Comment: With this approach, should I do my localstorage stuff in the subscribe or in the map function? Does it make sense to simply replace my map with the subscribe?

Comment: It depends on your logic. If you don't change response,  you can replace `map` with `tap`.

Comment: Essentially my logic is to store the token received from the server in the localstorage. That's it.

Comment: So look at the `tap` operator if you use higher than 5.5, else look at `do` operator

Comment: Sorry but the version i'm using is 5.5.7 and there is not "tap" operator. Online i found that is available only for v6 or higher. Also the "do" is not working as well. Should i also use the "subscribe" at the end as you did?

Comment: Yes, subscribe is required. `tap` must be there. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: I'll try with the subscribe but this is what i found about the tap operator: [TAP](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html)

Comment: Have you used `tap` with `pipe` function ?

Comment: No, i'm trying to use it as an operator, from what i can understand. With "DO" I get this error "TypeError: this.http.post(...).do is not a function
    at AuthenticationService.login"

Comment: So using higher `5.5` you need go with `pipe`